# Free error syntax but it keep gives me errors (function in plsql)

Tags: oracle, function, plsqldeveloper

In this function I'm creating a collection and this function goes and select the ids of the employees whose salary is out of the max and min range of salaries and return those ids in that collection , I think the syntax is true but it keeps giving me tow underlines : the first line (AS table) and the second line (Create) , ***

***the error:Type HR.ID_TABLE@HR Error(4,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" .***

---

, any ideas why this happening .

```
CREATE TYPE id_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION min_max RETURN id_table AS
l_emp_list id_table;
BEGIN
SELECT e.employee_id 
BULK COLLECT INTO l_emp_list
FROM employees e 
INNER JOIN jobs j ON j.job_id = e.job_id
WHERE e.salary NOT BETWEEN j.min_salary AND j.max_salary;

RETURN l_emp_list;
END;
```

Any help please , so I can fix it . THanks

Comment: Well, it would really help if maybe you showed the errors,no?

Comment: try adding `/` after the create type

Comment: PLEASE show your errors if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE id_table AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Where are you executing the script?

Comment: where are you executing that? do you get the same error if you create the type first and then in a different script create the function?